# Reading the wrong number of bytes from a binary file

Tags: tcl

I have the following code:

```
set myfile "the path to my file"
set fsize [file size $myfile]
set fp [open $myfile r]
fconfigure $fp -translation binary
set data [read $fp $fsize]
close $fp
puts $fsize
puts [string bytelength $data]
```

And it shows that the bytes read are different from the bytes requested. The bytes requested match what the filesystem shows; the actual bytes read are 22% more (requested 29300, got 35832). I tested this on Windows, with Tcl 8.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string length`. Don't use `string bytelength`. It gives the “wrong” answers, or rather it answers a question you probably don't want to ask.

### More Depth

The `string bytelength` command returns the length in bytes of the data in Tcl's internal almost-UTF-8 encoding. If you're not working with Tcl's C API directly, you really have no sensible use for that value, and C code is actually pretty able to get the value without that command. For ASCII text, the length and the byte-length are the same, but for binary data or text with NULs or characters greater than U+00007F (the Unicode character that is equivalent to ASCII DEL), the values will differ. By contrast, the `string length` command knows how to handle binary data correctly, and will report the number of bytes in the byte-string that you read in. We plan to deprecate the `string bytelength` command, as it turns out to be a bug in someone's code almost every time they use it.

(I'm guessing that your input data actually has 6532 bytes outside the range 1–127 in it; the other bytes internally use a two-byte representation in almost-UTF-8. Fortunately, Tcl doesn't actually convert into that format until it needs to, and instead uses a compact array of bytes in this case; you're forcing it by asking for the `string bytelength`.)

### Background Information

The question of “how much memory is actually being used by Tcl to read this data” is quite hard to answer, because Tcl will internally mutate data to hold it in the form that is most efficient for the operations you are applying to it. Because Tcl's internal types are all precisely transparent (i.e., conversions to and from them don't lose information) we *deliberately* don't talk about them much except from an optimisation perspective; as a programmer, you're supposed to pretend that Tcl has no types other than string of unicode characters.

You can peel the veil back a bit with the `tcl::unsupported::representation` command (introduced in 8.6). **Don't use the types for decisions on what to do** in your code, as that is really not something guaranteed by the language, but it does let you see a lot more about what is really going on under the covers. Just remember, the values that you see are not the same as the values that Tcl's implementation thinks about. Thinking about the values that you see (without that magic command) will keep you thinking about things that it is correct to write.

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. My next challenge is to pass that string to a command custom-built in C by means of Tcl_CreateCommand, without the raw binary string being altered by the interpreter.

Comment: @Eduardo Because of Tcl's almost-UTF8 encoding, the binary data will pass through C strings safely, meaning you can use `Tcl_NewStringObj(theStr, -1)` to store the argument in a `Tcl_Obj*` ref, and `Tcl_GetByteArrayFromObj` to access the binary bytes. The `unsigned char *` pointer it returns will be good until you `Tcl_DecrRefCount` the `Tcl_Obj*` (and you can also get it to tell you how long the buffer is via an optional out parameter, or at least what comes closest to that in C).

Comment: What `string bytelength` really returns is the `strlen` of the data that goes through the old-style calls.

Comment: Yes! I tried that, and it worked great! Thank you very much for the help!